# How to dynamically fill Text field based on select field option in `Nova Laravel`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

How can the text field be set based on the select box in Nova Laravel? (without using libraries)

eg: if the user selects **Option** as 100, **Option Name** should be "First Option"
(options array is dynamically called)

```
$options = [
    100 => "First Option"
    101 => "Second Option"
    102 => "Third Option"
  ];
```

```
Select::make('Option')->options($options),
Text::make('Option Name')->readonly();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same situation, I've used [NovaAjaxSelect\AjaxSelect](https://github.com/dillingham/nova-ajax-select)

Answer (score 1):

For someone stumble same question. I used this one on laravel nova4.

```
            $options = [
                100 => "First Option",
                200 => "Second Option"
            ];
            Select::make('Options')->options(
                $options
            )->required(),
            Text::make('Option Name')->readonly()->dependsOn(
                ['options'],
                function (
                    Text $field,
                    NovaRequest $request,
                    FormData $formData
                ) use ($options) {
                    $field->default(function ($request) use ($formData, $options){
                        return $options[$formData->options];
                    });
                }
            ),
```

You may create CustomText and Extends Text Field.
Override the resolveDefaultValue.  with this function.

Your field will listen to other field and change value of your text field to your choice.

```
    /**
     * Resolve the default value for the field.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function resolveDefaultValue(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        if ($this->defaultCallback instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func($this->defaultCallback, $request);
        }

        return $this->defaultCallback;
    }
```